# Why does stl() decomposition require integer frequency?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality, loess, decomposition

I need to decompose and forecast weekly series with around 10 years of data. In this data leap years play an important role so I need the have non-integer frequency, frequency = (365.25/7)

By reading the stl() vignette I realized that the frequency of series should always be an integer number but I am not quite sure that I understood it correctly.
example for weekly data:
F=52
[image]

for F=52.178

[image]

DATA:
c(2336,186,1563,987,1339,2542,978,1445,367,2836,890,3434,5389,9175,4469,11045,9473,11303,9372,5668,7576,7799,4282,4995,2457,3610,5725,320,3151,6690,7795,4310,3348,5415,5106,3742,4975,5165,2866,3990,2528,3721,1054,4717,4463,903,2035,4387,1751,2682,4889,3355,3796,5223,3129,2038,1760,2591,4372,2692,6354,6836,1983,4285,4446,1507,7089,694,247,10429,6873,16891,11285,10849,6914,7917,7318,6380,7800,6125,4557,5440,4243,11141,6698,3971,852,4485,3803,3896,1717,3062,6556,2301,2859,4140,6359,3069,2268,2612,6708,5308,5233,4578,6644,6310,5211,5058,3466,7697,6223,3952,4531,7809,7999,8066,19295,23812,20138,13374,20584,15934,14939,16724,14652,11569,10164,6911,9714,13141,12362,8075,7275,5622,3817,4933,6743,5437,8102,7927,5466,9497,7343,1762,5626,5508,4230,3316,4528,3215,7884,4577,3256,6681,6499,5016,2601,2384,3404,3640,3834,2922,6199,8887,8062,5899,801,9774,7897,10485,9792,15708,14301,12490,17142,15197,17464,19602,15500,12963,16513,12490,13902,10939,11892,9058,6946,9053,5011,11090,5124,7782,6162,4921,4460,4215,9498,6833,10164,9371,7632,5866,2405,1403,8716,3521,13422,5241,7201)